# jsPDF: How to write a Hindi string

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I am trying to write a hindi string in my pdf:

[image]

Why is the string converted to random characters? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

you have to include a custom hindi fornt for this ,
https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF#use-of-unicode-characters--utf-8

make the js file form ttf font ,and set the font in js doct

js file like

this

```
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";

export default function addFontNormal() {
  const font =
    "AAEAAAAUAQAABABAR0RFRln/ZIAAAkLIAAAOvkdQT1OIOAx8AAJRiAAATbRHU1VCnYRDqQACnzwAACo4SFZBUhZuBrQAAsl0AAARTk9TLzIBK3zuAAINAAAAAGBTVEFUAXn08QAC2sQAAADeYXZhcup/o07uilUf/e/9c/1z/XP9d/2j/ZP95/3n/ev96/3T/dP96/3r/bP94GIiTmaWlpaWlp6q9ytTa2trYx7/W4ODg1wBA/1mBPwUFAv34/v//AAH++v4EBAQD//8BAAIFBgYFBAQFAP8C...";
  const callAddFont = function () {
    this.addFileToVFS("NotoSansBengali.ttf", font);
    this.addFont("NotoSansBengali.ttf", "NotoSansBengali", "normal");
  };
  jsPDF.API.events.push(["addFonts", callAddFont]);
}
```

=>in jspd file

```
import addFontNormal from "../fonts/NotoSansBengali-normal";

addFontNormal();

console.log("font list", doc.getFontList());//check all added font

doc.setFont("NotoSansBengali", "normal");//set font before writhing
```

user your utf-8 hindi for for this //"im using a bangla font"